# makefile errors ***missing seprarator stop

Tags: makefile, imake

I have an Imakefile. I use `xmkmf -a` and get

`mv -f Makefile Makefile.bak
imake -DUseInstalled -I/usr/share/X11/config
make Makefiles
Makefile:1056: *** missing separator.   Stop.`

I shocked. I look in Makefile in LINE 1056.

`LocalCompileDefault`

is in this line. What's the problem now ????

Does it mean something wrong with Imakefile? 
But I check Makefile line 1056 and no space issue. ????????

I generate from `Imakefile` using `xmkmf -a`

lines above `LocalCompileDefault` are:

Some if and ifend statements are directly above.

`#if CPPBUILD 
      Files := $(Files) sample.file
      #endif`

Before that list of file

`Files=\
       sample1.file\
       sample2.file\
       etc...\
       finalfile`

before that

`VPATH = VpathDir:.
FINAL_OBJECT = idontknow.o`

Comment: I usually got this when space is used instead of `tab`

Comment: there is `no space` or `tab`

Comment: May be you should share the makefile

Comment: I sharing the line in question The FILE tOOO BIG TO SHARE

Comment: but if I add `tab` before `LocalCompileDefault` then I get message: `Makefile:1056: *** recipe comences bfore first target. Stop.`

Comment: please recall. I do not create makefile. I use `xmkmf` that generates `makefile`. So, `no space` might not be problem ??